# How to update profile image to twitter using REST api?

Tags: python, django, twitter, oauth-2.0

Is anybody have working code or sample to update Twitter profile image .?

python-oauth2 is good or not  .? Shall i use other library for this .. ?

Using : python 2.7 , Django 1.7 [python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2)

```
image_post = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=ThisOneWorksPerfectly"
resp, content = client.request(image_post, "POST")
```

Above code works perfectly fine but i changed that code to `update` `profile` `image` ( See below ... )

From this [update_profile_image](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile_image)

```
image_post = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_image.json?image={}".format(encodedImage)
resp, content = client.request(image_post, "POST")
```

Error:

```
'{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the image as a POST parameter, not as a query parameter. You can do so by providing a 3rd parameter (`body`) to the `client.request` method, as in:

```
image_post = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_image.json"
resp, content = client.request(image_post, "POST", "image=" + base64EncodedImage)
```

Comment: sorry, confused Python and PHP... fixed now ("+")

Comment: make sure you use the right image_post URL (edited in now) and paste the full error please if it persists

Comment: I can reproduce this "not recognized" error with my own profile/curl commands if I send bogus data instead of a valid base64 encoded picture.

Comment: after that using python-twitter i resolved my issue.